# Upload Image To Cloud Application in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, azure, windows-phone-8, cloud

I want to write a simple windows phone application which takes an image from the phone's camera and then upload it to my azure server which has a C# application for image processing and send the processed information back as text.

What would be the best way to communicate like this between the phone and the server ? Do I have to use something like BLOB ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way so far to upload images from the phone to a remote server is using the Windows.Networking.BackgroundTranfer API as shown in the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer